# Symfony validation to validate a simple value does not work with LessThan constraint

Tags: php, validation, symfony

it seems impossible to validate a simple value with the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThan` constraint.

Here is a simple test:

```
$lessConstraint = new LessThan();
$lessConstraint->value = 5;
$errors[] = $this->get('validator')->validateValue('This must fail.', $lessConstraint);
var_dump($errors);
```

I was expecting a constraint violation as the tested string is longer than 5 characters. But, the result is an empty `ConstraintViolationList` list:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList)#517 (1) { ["violations":"Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList":private]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Same problem with the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThanOrEqual` constraint. However, as shown [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays), it works perfectly with the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email` constraint: I get an error if the string is not an email.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually expected.

I am pretty sure you are meant to use `Range` constraint instead. So what does happen here?

According to `LessThanValidator` source file ([here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/LessThanValidator.php)) the comparison is done by simply using `<` operator on left and right operand.

Now, if you consult the `PHP`'s reference on type comparison ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)) there is this:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically

So, that being said, you should do:

```
$lessConstraint = new Range();
$lessConstraint->max = 5;
$errors[] = $this->get('validator')->validateValue('This must fail.', $lessConstraint);
var_dump($errors);
```

That's it. Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: You're right. Don't know why, but I assumed LessThan to test only strings, so I thought it would make the the conversion. In fact, I could also use this `$this->get('validator')->validateValue(strlen('This must fail.'), $lessConstraint);` and keep the LessThan constraint. Thanks for your help.